# Android Client-Side doesn't push Arabic Notifications

Tags: android, azure, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I used the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started)

for implementing the pushing from client side , but it doesn't send Arabic notification
what I have to change in this method to support Arabic

I'm also tried json.getBytes("UTF-8") but nothing sent , for ("Windows-1256") the message sent but false encoded the characters displayed as "???"

```
public void sendNotificationButtonOnClick(View v) {
 EditText notificationText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNotificationMessage);
 final String json = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"" + notificationText.getText().toString() + "\"}}";

 new Thread()
 {
     public void run()
     {
         try
         {
             ParseConnectionString(NotificationSettings.HubFullAccess);
             URL url = new URL(HubEndpoint + NotificationSettings.HubName +
                     "/messages/?api-version=2015-01");

             HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

             try {
                 // POST request
                 urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                 // Authenticate the POST request with the SaS token
                 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", 
                     generateSasToken(url.toString()));

                 // Notification format should be GCM
                 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ServiceBusNotification-Format", "gcm");

               urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", 
                 //        "tag1 || tag2 || tag3");

                 // Send notification message
                 urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(json.length());
                 OutputStream bodyStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                 bodyStream.write(json.getBytes());
                 bodyStream.close();

                 // Get reponse
                 urlConnection.connect();
                 int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                 if ((responseCode != 200) && (responseCode != 201)) {
                     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((urlConnection.getErrorStream())));
                     String line;
                     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Send Notification returned " +
                             responseCode + " : ")  ;
                     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                         builder.append(line);
                     }

                     ToastNotify(builder.toString());
                 }
             } finally {
                 urlConnection.disconnect();
             }
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             if (isVisible) {
                 ToastNotify("Exception Sending Notification : " + e.getMessage().toString());
             }
         }
     }
 }.start();
```

}

Comment: Could you try a test send from [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) using Arabic characters? I'm pretty it's going to work. Which means that the server supports it. Which means that there's something going on either with serialization in your code or possibly the code file itself is somehow encoded incorrectly. Also, why are you sending the request via REST API? There's a [Java SDK for Notification Hubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Android/GetStarted).

Comment: yes I've tried it and it works , I know that the problem in encoding the message itself in this method , and the Java SDK for Notification Hubs you posted here , is the same used in the tutorial I mentioned in my question with the same method ^^

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 var payload = new
        {
            to = fcm_token,
            priority = "high",
            content_available = true,
            notification = new
            {
                body = data.body,
                title = data.content,
                badge = 1,
                targetScreen = data.TargetScreen,
                Id = data.Id
            },
        };
        var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).ToString(); 
        var buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);

        request.GetRequestStream().Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
```

where payload is the object that you will send to firebase